# How to fix the Error Type 3 error on Android Studio?

Tags: android

My Android Studio does not work in any project. We are working as a theme and only i receive such an error on run:

```
04/17 02:08:47: Launching 'app' on Unknown Device.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.mellow.mellow/com.mellow.mellow.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.mellow.mellow/com.mellow.mellow.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mellow.mellow/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.mellow.mellow/com.mellow.mellow.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

The classes are there, but it does not see. 
I even started a new project to test, but it still gives me the same problem. What shall i try?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your MainActivity's package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who has a similar issue, I have wiped out the AVD emulator and it worked. You may try if you think it is not due to your project. But be careful on that, all the data will be removed from the virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the package for your Main Activity. It appears like you repeated the `com.mellow.mellow.MainActivity`twice. Also check the project structure in the studio.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, since it happened on multiple projects, i have thought that it is related to emulator so I wiped out the emulator, it worked for now.
But i will fix the name of the package.